# How to Using WebDriverWait Selenium to get the value of "style" element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

It changes to "display: block" at certain times. I want to wait until "display: block" and continue the time when that changes.

```
<div class="dialog transportxs pre_render" id="dialog_transport" style="z-index: 3; display: block;">
    <div data-tip="closeX" onclick="close_dialog('transport');" class="close"></div>
    <div class="main transport_transport"> xxx </div>
    <div class="disabled_controls" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="tutoverlay"></div>
</div>
```

I did as below and it gave error

```
wait = WebDriverWait(site, 20)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='dialog_transport']/div[3][contains(@style,'block')]")))
```

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\bb\Desktop\test\tes1111t.py", line 281, in <module>
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='dialog_transport']/div[3][contains(@style,'block')]")))
      File "C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.10\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
        raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the condition when that element has the disired attribute value, as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='disabled_controls'][contains(@style,'block')]")))
```

**UPD**
I can't debug, only guess, but I'll suggest trying this:

```py
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='dialog_transport']//div[@class='disabled_controls'][contains(@style,'block')]")))
```

Comment: There are too many results when we type as "disabled controls", can't find the right place.
I'm sending you the general code block, can you take a look at it again?

<div class="dialog transportxs pre_render" id="dialog_transport" style="z-index: 3; display: block;">
    <div data-tip="closeX" onclick="close_dialog('transport');" class="close"></div>
    <div class="main transport_transport"> xxx </div>
    <div class="disabled_controls" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="tutoverlay"></div>
</div>

Comment: It's not readable here. Please add this to the question and format it so it will be readable. If possible please add a link to the page you are working on, this may help

Comment: I edited it in the first post

Comment: I see. What element / attribute is unique there so we can build unique locator based on it? The `dialog_transport` id? maybe the `xxx` text?

Comment: I updated it, can you check it? It gave an error.

Comment: Please see my updated guess. Does `disabled_controls` class name not changing in that element for both visible and invisible states?

Comment: have you tried the updated answer?